# Number of occurrences of an element in a 2d-array c++

Tags: c++

If I'm given a 2d array say `{{1,2},{2,3,4},{5,1,2,7}}`, how do I count how many times an element say `1` has occurred in the array?
Is there any c++ STL function for this?

Comment: How is this 2d array declared?

Comment: `std::accumulate` over `std::count` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 2d array is nested standard library containers and the outer container is called `arr`:

```
auto target = 1;
auto count = std::accumulate(
    std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0,
    [target](auto a, auto const &inner) {
        return a + std::count(std::begin(inner), std::end(inner), target);
    }
);
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb3cd336b2ba7105))

This assumes C++14 support for an `auto` lambda parameter.

If the type of `arr` is `int**` then this will not work as `std::end()` will not know where each array ends, but you'd have exactly the same problem trying to iterate over the inner elements of that array manually.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "normal" 2D array, where the data is stored in contiguous memory, then usage of [std::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) is all that's required if you give it the start and ending location in memory.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
//...
int main()
{
   const int m=10;
   const int n=20;
   int arr[m][n] = {0};
   arr[0][0] = 1;
   arr[m-1][n-1] = 1;
   std::cout << "The number of 1's is " << std::count(&arr[0][0], &arr[m-1][n], 1);
}
```

Output:

```
The number of 1's is 2
```